# PrimeNG OrderList buttons remove

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to remove the top and bottom buttons from the component orderList.
[image]

The only thing I came up with was using css. I've tried selecting them by their icon attributes but got no luck.

**My CSS which is loaded after primeng css files:**

```
button[icon="fa-angle-double-up"] {
    display: none;
}

button[ng-reflect-icon="fa-angle-double-up"] {
    display: none;
}
```

**My component:**

```
@Component({
    template: `<p-orderList></p-orderList>`,
    styles: [`
        button[icon="fa-angle-double-up"] {
            display: none;
        }
        button[ng-reflect-icon="fa-angle-double-up"] {
            display: none;
        }
    `],

    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

So is there an another way to remove the buttons which I want or what is the correct way of doing this by css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
button[icon="fa-angle-double-up"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Another option: extend primeng component and redefine html template.

Comment: I've removed the `encapsulation` and `styles` options from the component and added `!important` to the css rule and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-orderlist-controls{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

use this in the SCSS file

Answer (score 2):

Put below css in **styles.css** file

```
body .ui-orderlist-controls {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div[class="p-orderlist-controls"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```